# This code is displaying only one message from inbox even if there are many messages. The cursor is not fetching the next message probably,

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, cursor

Cursor might have the problem, it is not fetching next position value. And that might be the problem to display only one message.

```js
try {
    if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {
            String msgData = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
            if (msgData.contains("sent") || msgData.contains("debited") || msgData.contains("recharge")) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msgData, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String eg[] = {
                    msgData
                };
                ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.row, R.id.lblMsg, eg);
                lvMsg.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                //c.moveToNext();
                /*Adapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row, c,
                        new String[]{"body", "address"}, new int[]{
                        R.id.lblMsg, R.id.lblNumber});
                lvMsg.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);*/
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
} catch (Exception ee) {
    ee.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @pskink yes, I tried using that, but its not accepting the array value. The toast that is commented, works fine and displays all the messages in toast but this is not working for displaying those messages in listview.

Comment: @pskink That "c" is a cursor variable

Comment: @pskink thank you for the help, but I couldn't understand much, can you please elaborate?

Comment: @pskink I have did that, the one that has commented, but there was not even a single message as now it is displaying only one.

Comment: @pskink yes, tried and the one that is commented in the post, its the same I guess, but that's not displaying anything...

Comment: @pskink It is  not showing any message in logcat neither in the app

Comment: @pskink Only one row, so cursor is just fetching one row and not fetching the rest

Comment: @pskink no not anything